# UIScrollView the subviews added but can not slide to them

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
MyData *data = [MyData SharedData];

scrollerView.pagingEnabled = YES;
scrollerView.bounces = YES;

int numberOfViews = [data.placePhotos count];
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {

    CGFloat yOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;
    UIView *awesomeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(yOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    awesomeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300 , 320)];

    NSString * photourl = [[data.placePhotos objectAtIndex:i] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"150x75" withString:@"440x440"];

    [imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:photourl]];
    [awesomeView addSubview:imageView];

    [scrollerView addSubview:awesomeView];
    awesomeView = nil;
    imageView =nil;
}
```

I added the UIScrollView in the .xib file , when i tried to pull the scroll view from left to right it does not move, i have 4 subviews added but why i can not view them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should set the content size the scrollView

```
     [self. scrollerView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1000)];
```

Give your width and heigth.

Comment: just an example ofcourse. it needs to be the value of the last element position +its heigth.

Comment: yes i evaluate the width and height of my view and set the correct value

Answer (score 0):

add `scrollerView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(yOrigin + self.view.frame.size.width, scrollerView.frame.size.height);` after the loop (even though I'm a little bit confused about why the x-origin is called `yOrigin` in your code...)